# C# - Reverse Point3D Collection

Tags: c#

How can I invert the order of this Point3DCollection? Basically I want the last points to be the first and vise-versa.

```
 Point3DCollection finalPointsTube;
 //reverse finalPointsTube??
```

Comment: First off... maybe you think you just added "useful" code but its not telling us a thing as it doesn't even have a value yet (so cant be reversed). Second, `Reverse()` is an available extension method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.point3dcollection_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Have you tried: `finalPointsTube.Reverse()`?

Comment: Reverse is only for a list.